# Django custom admin login template - form doesn't load, no input tags

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to make my own custom admin login template, so I just moved the login.html template to /templates/admin. The template loads, but there are input boxes. It's as if the form isn't being passed to this template file now and I have no idea why. The same code works on my development server, but when I put it on an actual server, the form just doesn't load. Am I missing a setting or something?

Answer (score 0):

It could happen for a lot of reasons.

1. **Make sure your TEMPLATE_DIRS is set properly.** - Well since you said it is loading, I bet it is set but wont hurt to double check.
2. **Make sure the blocks that display content are correct.** - Of course, parts of the pages will fail to display if you have, say a mistyped or missing block. For easy reference, here is the code for [login.html](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html) in the admin and the [base_site.html](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html) that it extends.
3. If you are using a custom view, make sure to give the correct template path. - If your template root directory is in /templates, you should render the page in 'admin/login.html'.

Just a bit of advice, do  a `FORM HERE >> {{ form }}` somewhere in your template to check if it actually has a value. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment below i experienced the same issue, upgrading Django to the newest version in my server ( 1.3.1 ) fixed this issue.